# Element Plus and Vue using Menu hover effect not changable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, hover

Hey guys im really new to Vue, HTML, CSS and Element Plus. I wanted to create a Side Bar Menu with your own hover effect. However this is not changable. If you change the *background-color* of *el-menu* to anything, the hover effect vanishes. I've tried using *:hover* on the *el-menu* element and change the *back-ground-color* but this does not seem to work either. The default hover effect color is light blue but i need it in lightgray.

I am using **Vue3**

The Sidebar I want to use is from here: https://element-plus.org/en-US/component/menu.html#side-bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I tried to test it from element-plus playground and it works fine when I override it from el-menu class.
[here](https://element-plus.run/#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) is the link I tested. could you please add more detail.

Comment: Hey thank you it worked! Could you explain me how? :)

This is the line i adjusted: 

.el-menu-vertical .el-menu-item:hover,.el-menu-vertical .el-sub-menu__title:hover